# gdal_translate NetCDF to GeoTiff file conversion not working

Tags: gdal, netcdf, netcdf4, geotiff

I am new to geospatial analytics and using NetCDF and GeoTIFF files. I am trying to convert the NetCDF file into GeoTIFF file. I came across this reference: [netcdf-to-geotiff-file-conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153528/netcdf-to-geotiff-file-conversion). I have successfully installed and can run `gdal_translate` in my MacOS terminal. However, I get this message I am trying to understand what this means and what I am missing? This appears to be warning, however it didn't generate any output.

My code executed:

`gdal_translate some_nc_file_name.nc output.tif`

Error/Message:

```
Warning 1: No UNIDATA NC_GLOBAL:Conventions attribute
Input file contains subdatasets. Please, select one of them for reading.
```

Here is my data output I previewed in Python:

[image]

Comment: can you post the `gdalinfo` output for `some_nc_file_name.nc`?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have multiple variables in the file, so need to select one. Example (following https://nsidc.org/support/how/how-convert-golive-netcdf-variables-geotiff).

```
gdal_translate NETCDF:"Input_FileName.nc":variable_name Output_FileName.tif
```

Based on the warning message, the netCDF file lacks certain important attributes, so some issues may exist with the coordinates etc. in the tif.